# Trying to execute code from a different page. Not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm calling this function in a swift file but it doesn't seem to work. For example, the timer isn't stopping when it's supposed to. Any ideas on how to fix it from the code shown below? Thanks.

```
var vc = ViewController()
            func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
            {
                vc.endGame()
                vc.startButton!.hidden = false
                vc.timer!.invalidate()
              vc.timer = nil
                // This is calling the function from the view controller
                return true
            }
```

Comment: You say you're calling a function but what you're showing is the function that iOS calls when you app starts up.  Can you explain a bit more about what's going on in the app?

Comment: @PhillipMills It's a snake arcade game. I have the game functions in the view controller, but more so the borders/boundaries in this swift file. When the snake hits the wall (the end of the screen/border) I need it to call the endgame function from the other controller. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @PhillipMills never mind i solved it another way

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question. You can post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.